# Removing .jpg from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, image-processing, url-rewriting

I have rewrite rule that redirects users who try directly open image to the website post but I need to remove .jpg from url:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^reviews-image/([^/]+) /image-2/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Example: http://www.example.com/reviews-image/2015-lincoln-mkc-3.jpg to http://www.example.com/image-2/2015-lincoln-mkc-3.jpg

But I want remove **.jpg** from link so it would be **http://www.example.com/image-2/2015-lincoln-mkc-3**. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^reviews-image/([^/]+)\.jpg /image-2/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```